# Cross-validating an ordinal logistic regression in R (using rpy2)

Tags: r, regression, cross-validation, python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to create a predictive model in Python, comparing several different regression models through cross-validation. In order to fit an ordinal logistic model (`MASS.polr`), I've had to interface with R through `rpy2` as follows:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects as ro

df = pd.DataFrame()
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({"y":25,"X":7},index=[0]))
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({"y":50,"X":22},index=[0]))
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({"y":25,"X":15},index=[0]))
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({"y":75,"X":27},index=[0]))
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({"y":25,"X":12},index=[0]))
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({"y":25,"X":13},index=[0]))

# Loads R packages. 
base = importr('base')
mass = importr('MASS')

# Converts df to an R dataframe. 
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
ro.globalenv["rdf"] = pandas2ri.py2ri(df) 

# Makes R recognise y as a factor. 
ro.r("""rdf$y <- as.factor(rdf$y)""")

# Fits regression. 
formula = "y ~ X"    
ordlog = mass.polr(formula, data=base.as_symbol("rdf"))
ro.globalenv["ordlog"] = ordlog
print(base.summary(ordlog))
```

So far, I have mainly been comparing my models using `sklearn.cross_validation.test_train_split` and `sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score`, yielding a number from 0 to 1 which represents the accuracy of the training-set model in predicting the test-set values.

How might I replicate this test using `rpy2` and `MASS.polr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem eventually solved by refitting the model using `rms.lrm`, which provides a `validate()` function (interpreted following [this example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23238/cross-validation-and-ordinal-logistic-regression)).